# Get all BTS tower when receive an SMS

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I can get bts info in one activity , but when use that code in OnRecive of this code it is not work , Why this code can not get bts tower?

```
package com.example.testneighbore;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.telephony.NeighboringCellInfo;
        import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import java.util.List;


public class SMS extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, " START ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            List<NeighboringCellInfo> NeighboringList = telephonyManager.getNeighboringCellInfo();

            String retStr="";
            for (int i = 0; i < NeighboringList.size(); i++) {

                int cid = NeighboringList.get(i).getCid();
                int lac = NeighboringList.get(i).getLac();
                retStr += "&" + cid + "," + lac + ",";

            }
            Toast.makeText(context,"Print: "+ retStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(context, " END ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }


}
```

My AndroidManifest.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testneighbore"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testneighbore.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".SMS">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES"/>
</manifest>
```

I think my main problem is with Context, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your  problem is related to context, because the context is involved with receiving sms. To solve this problem, you have to make thread and get bts info in it. it is better that your thread to be call within ~20 seconds delay . you can use omething like this in OnRecieve()

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
                       // get info 

      }
 }, 20000);
```